# Android studio Wi-fi

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio does not show my device in the devices list and so therefore I cannot test my apps on a physical device over Wi-fi. I have put my android device into developer mode and enabled Wireless debugging.

I am running Android Studio 4.2
Build: #AI-202.7660.26.42.732048

The physical device I would like to use to test my apps is:
Galaxy S10 running Android version 11.0

Comment: Far more info seems needed. What device? What version of Android is it running? What version of Android Studio? etc.

Comment: What is the output of `adb devices` in a terminal? Does it work when the phone is connected via USB? *After* it has been connected via USB?

Comment: 'adb is not recognized as an internal or external command'. The trouble is that the USB port on my phone is a bit loose and I cannot connect to it.